# Don't understand how to parse URDF file

Tags: xml, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Indigo.

So I am following the URDF tutorial ([Create your own urdf file](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20urdf%20file)) but after I create my .urdf file I don't understand how to parse it.
The file is located in

> /home/<user_name>/ROS/catkin_ws/src/learning_urdf/urdf/robot.urdf

where:

- catkin_ws -- my ROS workspace
- learning_urdf -- a package I created
  for this tutorial

the code in the robot.urdf is

```
<robot name="test_robot">
  <link name="link1" />
  <link name="link2" />
  <link name="link3" />
  <link name="link4" />

  <joint name="joint1" type="continuous">
    <parent link="link1"/>
    <child link="link2"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="joint2" type="continuous">
    <parent link="link1"/>
    <child link="link3"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="joint3" type="continuous">
    <parent link="link3"/>
    <child link="link4"/>
  </joint>
</robot>
```

and finally I run the command:

```
check_urdf robot.urdf
```

and get this error:

```
Error:   Error document empty.
         at line 72 in /build/buildd/urdfdom-0.2.10+dfsg/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
ERROR: Model Parsing the xml failed
```

Looking more I found [this](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf#Verification) but still not sure what to do. Do I need to run a command similar to this

> rosrun xacro xacro.py `rospack find pr2_description`/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro
> -o /tmp/pr2.urdf

Do I need to first convert it to a xarco or somthing?

Where does to urdf file need to be for the command to run?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215648/don%27t-understand-how-to-parse-urdf-file/) by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2015-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run `check_urdf /home/<user_name>/ROS/catkin_ws/src/learning_urdf/urdf/robot.urdf` to parse your file. Path of your urdf file should be supplied or you should be in the same directory before running check_urdf.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2015-08-11**:
@UnfoX somebody needs to add that in the tutorial. Thanks very much for your help :)

**Comment by [RAHUL AGRAWAL](https://answers.ros.org/users/26519/rahul-agrawal/) on 2016-04-13**:
I am facing same problem and i tried with full path name but still failed.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-04-19**:
@RAHUL AGRAWAL, what is your command and console output?

**Comment by [Soul Goumey](https://answers.ros.org/users/30230/soul-goumey/) on 2017-05-09**:
I had the same problem, but it works now. i just went in the directory and after i run check_urdf my_robot.urdf.thank you really

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2017-05-10**:
@Soul Goumey, You're welcome!